# solve the ode $y^3y''=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the ode $y^3y''=1$. I used $$p=y'$$ and $$y''=pp'$$ then I got $$\frac{1}{-y^2}=-p^2+c$$ what should I do next?

Comment: $pp'=y'y''\neq y''$

Comment: Yes I am sure, this how it appears in the HW.

Comment: $pp'$=$y''$ while $(pp')'=y'y''$

Answer (score 2):

HINT :
$$y''=y^{-3}$$
$$2y''y'=2y^{-3}y'$$
$$(y')^2=-y^{-2}+c$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=\pm\sqrt{-y^{-2}+c}$$
This is a separable ODE. I suppose that you can continue.

Comment: Yes exactly I arrived to this,  but no I did not know how to continue

Comment: $$x=\pm\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{-y^{-2}+c}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y^3y''=1$$
$$y^3\frac {dy'}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}=1$$
$$y^3y'\frac {dy'}{dy}=1$$
Integrate
$$\int y'dy'=\int \frac {dy}{y^3}$$
$$( y'y)^2+Ky^2=-1$$
$$( \frac 1 2 (y^2)')^2+Ky^2=-1$$
Substitute $z=y^2$ and integrate

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sqrt z$ to make
$$2 z z''-z'^2=4$$ *Assuming* that $z$ is a polynomial in $x$,say $z=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, you should find
$$a_2=\frac{a_1^2+4}{4 a_0}\qquad a_3=0\qquad a_4=0\qquad a_n=0 \,\, \forall n >2$$
So, we have
$$z=a_0+a_1 x+\frac{a_1^2+4}{4 a_0}x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

From $y'=\pm\sqrt{-y^{-2}+c}$ one obtains $yy'=\pm \sqrt{cy^2-1}$.

This integrates (separable variables) to $\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{cy^2-1}=\pm x+C$ and so $$cy^2-1=(cx+a)^2$$
$$y^2=cx^2+2ax+\frac{a^2+1}{c}.$$